# How do I have subdomain.domain.com/ugly/path load subdomain.domain.com/newpath?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've spent a lot of time looking around and have unfortunately not been able to come up with anything that works.

I have an address in the following format:

```
subdomain.domain.com/ugly/path
```

that I want to prettify to:

```
subdomain.domain.com/newpath
```

How do I do this using .htaccess?

I'm not sure if this changes anything but the subdomain is simply an A record pointing to an IP address. There is no folder on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+ugly/path/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302] 

RewriteRule ^newpath(/.*)?$ ugly/path$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: .htaccess is placed in the root (which for my server is httpdocs). I've also tried placing it in the domain specific folder, but I'm unsure if that is correct given that this subdomain doesn't have a folder, and it doesn't work anyway. subdomain.domain.com/ugly/path works as expected.

Comment: As stated in the question the subdomain is simply an A record pointing at a public IP of another server. I do not have control over that other server. It seems like this is going to be an issue?

Comment: It's set up using FileMaker and I have no idea how it's working but it is. I do not have any access to make changes to that server though.

Comment: So I guess I should be asking whether I can do this when another server that I can't access is involved. It sounds like no?

Comment: No you cannot. .htaccess must be placed on the host a domain is pointed to.

Answer (score -1):

if the /ugly/ really is not necessary than you can simply move the content to your subdomain folder.

what you have currently is ...............

subdomain.domain.com/ugly/path1      (rootfolder/subdomain/ugly/path1)

subdomain.domain.com/ugly/path2      (rootfolder/subdomain/ugly/path1)

what you need to change is ............

rootfolder/subdomain/ugly/path1  ---> rootfolder/subdomain/path1

rootfolder/subdomain/ugly/path1  ---> rootfolder/subdomain/path1

Comment: As I said, I don't have a folder on the server. The path is predetermined by an external factor that I can't change. I can only, hopefully, use a prettier path to access the same location.